# biblatex-chicago & 2 more origdate problems

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

1. My bibliography has two works by the same author originally published in 1523, but for one the date is 1523, and for the other origdate is 1523.  Both show up as Aristotle 1523 (i.e. not 1523a and 1523b).
2. Another pair of works have a interlocking chronology, so to speak.  The first work was published in 1736-7 (origyear), but I cite the 2nd edn. of 1739 (year); the second was published in 1738-9 (year; no origyear).  In the bibliography the first work listed is Wolff 1738--1739, and the second, Wolff 1736--1737.  I need the reverse.

Are these are bugs, or am I doing something wrong?  Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
  \renewbibmacro*{origyear+endyear}{%
    \printfield{origyear}%
    \iffieldundef{origendyear}%
    {}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{origendyear}{}%
      {\mbox{\bibdatedash}}%
      {\bibdatedash\nopunct\printtext{\unspace}\printfield{origendyear}}}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @Book{aristotle1523a,
    author       = {Aristotle},
    title          = {Parva naturalia},
    publisher    = {Vitali},
    year           = 1523,
    location     = {Venice},
    translator   = {{Leonico Tomeo}, Niccol\`{o}}}
  @Book{aristotle1523b,
    author       = {Aristotle},
    editor       = {Agostino Nifo},
    title          = {Parva naturalia Augustini Niphi Medices
                    Philosophi Suessani},
    publisher    = {Scoto},
    year           = 1550,
    origdate     = 1523,
    options      = {cmsdate=on},
    location     = {Venice}}
@Book{wolff1736,
  author       = {Christian Wolff},
  title        = {Theologia naturalis methodo scientifica pertractata},
  publisher    = {Renger},
  year         = 1739,
  address      = {Frankfurt am Main},
  edition      = 2,
  options      = {cmsdate=on},
  origdate     = {1736/1737}}
@Book{wolff1738,
  author       = {Christian Wolff},
  title        = {Philosophia practica universalis methodo scientifica
                  pertractata},
  publisher    = {Renger},
  year         = {1738--1739},
  address      = {Frankfurt am Main},
  volumes      = 2}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: As as aside: if you are interested in emphasizing the differences between these editions (ad #1), wouldn't it make more sense to sort them by editor and translator?  (And isn't it weird to say that Aristotle is the author of *Parva naturalia Augustini Niphi [...]*..?)

Comment: Ad #2: you can use `sortyear = {1736/1737},` to force sorting.  These are complicated date requirements, so I'm not sure if `biblatex-chicago` 'should' be required to figure out the correct sorting in these cases....  And having to add something (say) to the `options` field is hardly going to be better than adding a whole separate field.

Comment: I forgot about sortyear; thanks.  Yes, the title is confusing.  Nifo is the editor and the commentator; he also adds a section or two.  But the book is primarily an edition of Aristotle's Parva naturalia.  Each section begins with a title like, "Aristotelis de animalium motu cum Augustini Niphi ... commentariis."  Presumably the publisher assumes that everyone will know that Aristotle is the author of the PN, although it is unusual not to put his name on the title-page.

Comment: Indeed, and the section title makes perfect sense: 'with the comments/commentary of Augustine Nipho'. It sounds to me like the selling point of the book from the publisher's view is that it is Nifo's *edition* of the PN (and probably his commentaries). What I meant to suggest was that one way out of this dilemma is to reference the work as Nifo's (if you like, stick an '[Aristotelis]' in the title). After all, no one really thinks the text in Nifo's book is Aristotle's in the strict sense of the word. (But then I would list Ross' edition of the PN under Ross, not Aristotle, so I'm biased!)

Comment: Anyway, that rant aside, the problem is that `biblatex/biber` is told that the `labelyear` is 1550 in teh Nifo entry, which is not surprising, but which makes it impossible for you to get a 1523a and 1523b (you can look at the `.bbl`).  If you make another Nifo entry for `date = 1550` without any `origyear` stuff, you'll see it listed as `1550b`.  It is too late for me to look, but I suspect the tests for duplicate dates will need to be made (much) more complex in order to catch same years in `origdate` fields.  (Although maybe the functionality is already mostly put in place.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `biblatex` respect `origdate` for the `labeldate`, which will enable the `extrayear` disambiguation feature for `origyear` as well. You will then have to modify some macros for proper display.
Please be aware that this might be quite a unpredictable fix in other situations, especially since `biblatex-chicago` has a very widely ramified conditional apparatus to facilitate date printing.

Number 2 can either be facilitated by `sortyear` or by giving `origyear` a higher priority than `date`/`year` in the sorting scheme.

Since both modifications are quite long, please have a look at the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

%----------- 1 -------------------------------------------%
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{origdate}
  \field{date}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:origyear+labelyear}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
    {\clearfield{extrayear}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}%<------ this is new

\renewbibmacro*{origyear+labelyear}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}%
    \clearfield{year}}%
  {\usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}}%<----- this is new

\newbibmacro*{standard+labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}%
    {\ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{misc}}
        or
        test {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inreference}}
        or
        test {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{reference}}
        or
        not togl {cms@nodates}}%
      {}%
      {\bibstring{nodate}}}%
    {\iffieldundef{year}%
      {\iffieldundef{eventyear}
        {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
          {\printfield{labelyear}%
            \iffieldundef{extrayear}%
            {}%
            {\setunit*{}%
              \printfield{extrayear}}%
            \iffieldundef{urlendyear}%
            {\clearfield{urlyear}}%
            {\iffieldequalstr{urlendyear}{}%
              {\mbox{\bibdatedash}%
                \clearfield{urlyear}}%
              {\iffieldundef{urlmonth}%
                {\clearfield{urlyear}}%
                {\iffieldsequal{urlyear}{urlendyear}%
                  {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlendyear}}%
                  {}}}}}%
          {\printfield{labelyear}%
            \iffieldundef{extrayear}%
            {}%
            {\setunit*{}%
              \printfield{extrayear}}%
            \iffieldundef{origendyear}%
            {\clearfield{origyear}}%
            {\iffieldequalstr{origendyear}{}%
              {\mbox{\bibdatedash}%
                \clearfield{origyear}}%
              {\iffieldundef{origmonth}%
                {\clearfield{origyear}}%
                {\iffieldsequal{origyear}{origendyear}%
                  {\clearfield{origyear}\clearfield{origendyear}}%
                  {}}}}}}%
        {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \iffieldundef{extrayear}%
          {}%
          {\setunit*{}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}%
          \iffieldundef{eventendyear}%
          {\clearfield{eventyear}}%
          {\iffieldequalstr{eventendyear}{}%
            {\mbox{\bibdatedash}%
              \clearfield{eventyear}}%
            {\iffieldundef{eventmonth}%
              {\clearfield{eventyear}}%
              {\iffieldsequal{eventyear}{evendendyear}%
                {\clearfield{eventyear}\clearfield{eventendyear}}%
                {}}}}}}%
      {\printfield{labelyear}%
        \iffieldundef{extrayear}%
        {}%
        {\setunit*{}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}%
        \iffieldundef{endyear}% DATE FIX
        {\iffieldundef{origyear}%<----- this conditional is new
          {\clearfield{year}}%
          {}}%
        {\iffieldequalstr{endyear}{}%
          {\mbox{\bibdatedash}%
            \clearfield{year}}%
          {\iffieldundef{month}%
            {\clearfield{year}}%
            {\iffieldsequal{year}{endyear}%
              {\clearfield{year}\clearfield{endyear}}%
              {}}}}}}}
\makeatother
%----------- 1 END -------------------------------------%

\renewbibmacro*{origyear+endyear}{%
  \printfield{origyear}%
  \iffieldundef{origendyear}%
  {}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{origendyear}{}%
    {\mbox{\bibdatedash}}%
    {\bibdatedash\nopunct\printtext{\unspace}\printfield{origendyear}}}}

%----------- 2 ----------------------------------------%
\DeclareSortingScheme{cms}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \name{sortname}
    \name{author}
    \name{namea}
    \name{editor}
    \name{nameb}
    \name{translator}
    \name{namec}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{journaltitle}
    \list{organization}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{origyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}
%----------- 2 END -------------------------------------%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{crusius1749,
  author       = {Christian August Crusius},
  title        = {Anleitung {\"u}ber nat{\"u}rliche Begebenheiten ordentlich
                  und vorsichtig nachzudencken},
  publisher    = {Gleditsch},
  year         = 1749,
  address      = {Leipzig}
}

@Book{crusius1754,
  author       = {Christian August Crusius},
  title        = {Gr{\"u}ndliche Belehrung vom Aberglauben zur Aufkl{\"a}rung
                  des Unterschiedes zwischen Religion und Aberglauben},
  publisher    = {Langenheim},
  year         = 1767,
  address      = {Leipzig},
  translator   = {Christian Friedrich Pezold},
  options      = {cmsdate=on},
  origdate     = {1754/1755}
}
@Book{aristotle1523a,
    author       = {Aristotle},
    title          = {Parva naturalia},
    publisher    = {Vitali},
    year           = 1523,
    location     = {Venice},
    translator   = {{Leonico Tomeo}, Niccol\`{o}}}
  @Book{aristotle1523b,
    author       = {Aristotle},
    editor       = {Agostino Nifo},
    title          = {Parva naturalia Augustini Niphi Medices
                    Philosophi Suessani},
    publisher    = {Scoto},
    year           = 1550,
    origdate     = 1523,
    options      = {cmsdate=on},
    location     = {Venice}}
@Book{wolff1736,
  author       = {Christian Wolff},
  title        = {Theologia naturalis methodo scientifica pertractata},
  publisher    = {Renger},
  year         = 1739,
  address      = {Frankfurt am Main},
  edition      = 2,
  options      = {cmsdate=on},
  origdate     = {1736/1737}}
@Book{wolff1738,
  author       = {Christian Wolff},
  title        = {Philosophia practica universalis methodo scientifica
                  pertractata},
  publisher    = {Renger},
  year         = {1738--1739},
  address      = {Frankfurt am Main},
  volumes      = 2}

@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  pages         = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  publisher     = {Peter Ublisher \& Co.},
  location      = {Place City},
}
@book{testbookt,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {A Second Book},
  date          = {2013},
  publisher     = {Peter Ublisher \& Co.},
  location      = {Place City},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite \cite{crusius1754}, \cite{testbook} and \cite{testbookt}, and \cite{wolff1738}.
As well as \cite{aristotle1523a} and \cite{aristotle1523b}.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: @GeorgePigman -- I would alert the author of `biblatex-chicago` to these issues and these solutions in case he wants to incorporate them or do something different.

Comment: A preliminary look at the bibliography with the fix for the first problem doesn't reveal any new problems, but I will keep my eyes open.  I am alerting the author of biblatex-chicago.